# Conversion from DataGridView to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

these two functions take care of converting a datagridview into a datatable using c # when the conversion is carried out the file is printed on the pdf, but the name of the columns is embossed once the printing is done in pdf, how can I solve this? I have to make the column name appear

**C# Code:**

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
            {
                if (column.Visible)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add();
                }
            }

            object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
            }

            return dt;
        }

        public void createPDF(DataTable dataTable, string destinationPath)
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataTable.Columns.Count);
            table.WidthPercentage = 100;

            //Set columns names in the pdf file
            for (int k = 0; k < dataTable.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataTable.Columns[k].ColumnName));

                cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(51, 102, 102);

                table.AddCell(cell);
            }

            //Add values of DataTable in pdf file
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataTable.Rows[i][j].ToString()));
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }
            }

            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'embossed'? You are setting a background color for your headers. So, if you don't like the color, then change that line to a different color

Comment: Side note. You are excluding the not visible columns from your headers, but you don't do the same thing for the cells that belongs to the invisible column. This could cause data misalignment if there is an invisible column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the foreach loop that adds columns:

dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(string));

Or alternatively:

dt.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText, typeof(string));

So it would look like this:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
 {
       if (column.Visible)
       {
           dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(string));
       }
 }
```

I haven't tested this code but you have to explicitly add names to the Columns, tell me if it works...

Comment: By default if you add a column without specifying the type then it is assumed to be of type string. So your code doesn't change anything

Comment: OK, but notice I explicitly set the column name?

Comment: Fine, but even with this addition, if you add a column without a name then a name is provided by the internal code with the pattern Column1, Column2 etc... The problem here is the 'embossed' word that seems to indicate a problem with the PDF creation and not with the datatable itself. The question title is misleading but without the proper clarification I cannot say anything